# How to Fix "invalid literal for int<> with base 10" error in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a script to convert some media files and when i do the script is returning the error `invalid literal for int<> with base 10: line 132`. This is not my script nor is it supported by the author which is why i'm here looking for assistance.

```
# Make time human-readable
def humanize_time(secs): ## Line:132
    if secs != "N/A":
        mins, secs = divmod(int(secs), 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)
    else:
        mins, secs = divmod(30, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\conv2mp4-py.py", line 415, in <module>
codec_discovery()
File "C:\conv2mp4-py.py", line 165, in codec_discover
get_duration_temp = humanize_time(head)
File "C:\conv2mp4-py.py", line 132, in humanize_time
mins, secs = divmod(int(secs), 60)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The Script: https://github.com/BrianDMG/conv2mp4-py/blob/master/conv2mp4-py.py

Comment: It is implying that you are trying to convert a non-int value to an int value with a decimal base of 10. Try to wrap the conversion in a `try except` block

Comment: I can't see *"line 132"*. Can you show where exactly is the error, also the complete traceback and [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the value of `secs` when you are doing `int(secs)`? It wont be a number & hence the error.

Comment: Just print the value of `secs` before the first `divmod` call. It clearly isn't what you expect.

Comment: Do not call `humanize_time` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `secs` variable is empty or contains a space in it. Check if the string is empty or not if you can guarantee the value of `secs` doesn't have a space included.

```
# Make time human-readable
Line:132 def humanize_time(secs):
    if secs != "":
        mins, secs = divmod(int(secs), 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)
    else:
        mins, secs = divmod(30, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of implementing such function is:

```
def humanize_time(secs=30):
    mins, secs = divmod(int(secs), 60)
    hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
    return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)
```

But in this case you have to take care of which parameter you pass to it.

If you have no control over the input, you'll have to implement exception management:

```
def humanize_time(secs=30):
    try: 
        mins, secs = divmod(int(secs), 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, mins, secs)
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        raise ValueError("Invalid value for 'secs': '" + str(secs) + "'")

print humanize_time(12)  #>> 00:00:12
print humanize_time("a")   #>> ValueError: Invalid value for 'secs': 'a'
```